# Update onClick ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im making a click speed test, but the counter doesn't update even tho the value does change, i think it is a problem with the useState hook but im not sure.

Here's the code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './app.css';

let contador = 0;
function hasClicked() {
  contador++;
  console.log(contador);
}
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <body>
        <h1>Click Speed Test</h1>
        <h2>{contador}</h2>
        <button onClick={hasClicked}>Click on Me</button>
      </body>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I need the H2 that displays the number to update every click.

Comment: you've imported `useState` but not actually used it (no pun intended). `contador` needs to be a React state variable so that its value is "remembered" between renders, and updating it triggers a new render. As it is your component never rerenders, but even if it did, `contador` would always be 0.

Comment: [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) have an excellent simple example of how to use the state hook, which is essentially identical to your own use case

Answer (score 2):

React is reactive, in that once you change its state, it will re-render the component and reflect changes in your state. Keep in mind, React does not know when you alter *any* variable. React will only know if you update a state value, which you must manually create. You're in the right direction by importing `useState`. Also, keep in mind that your state *must* only be *inside a component*, not in a global scope. Here's what your code should look something like:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './app.css';

function App() {
  const [contador, setContador] = useState(0); // declare our state

  function hasClicked() {
    setContador(contador + 1); // update state
    // calling this function also tells React to re-render the component
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <body>
        <h1>Click Speed Test</h1>
        {/* each time the component renders it displays
            the value of 'contador', which is altered on each click */}
        <h2>{contador}</h2>
        <button onClick={hasClicked}>Click on Me</button>
      </body>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```